# Regex String Replacement and Split using PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, string-formatting

I have a sample string in PHP:

```
$var = 'lurm limsrh domw en wonf src="@storage//user1/path/file.txt" and any lorm lipsm tjp quor it src="@storage//user2/path/file.txt" utt fine @storage// no chnge';
```

I want following operation using **PHP**:

1. Replace only those *@storage//* which is inside *src=""* to *http://mydomain/folder/*
2. Replace all user to md5(user);. The username must comes after *@storage//* i.e. it comes between *'@storage//'* and the *next '/'*. Also replace only those which are inside *src=""*

Which regular expression can I use for that?

Comment: um include `src="` in your search for `@storage` maybe?  is user1 the same as `Replace all user to md(user);`  This could be done with str_replace.  or `/src=\"@storage\/\/user/`

Comment: Yes,, user1is a user name

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/tK8cL1/2

Comment: Okey , and 2nd quistion how to replace??

Comment: If i am going to replace "src" replaces too

Comment: Does this not work `src="http://mydomain/folder/` as the replacement?  Nothing wrong with putting `src="` back in, Keep it simple.

Comment: I got frist . But sill q.no.2 not            how to get user name. And then replace with md5() of same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = 'http://mydomain/folder/';
$var = preg_replace_callback('/(.*?\bsrc)\s*=\s*"\s*@storage\/\/([^\/]+)([^"]+?)\s*"/s', function($matches) use ($url) {
    return $matches[1] . '="' . $url . md5($matches[2]) . $matches[3] . '"';
}, $var);
```

Sorry, can't test, but should be right.